# Problem with an Access 2007 Project connecting to Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access, ms-access-2007, access-data-project

So I've created an Access Project for one of my users so he can connect to a reporting database.  The .adp project connects to the DB and he can query data to his heart's content.  The problem is, no queries can be saved.  Whenever he opens the project, he is presented with the following error:

*"This version of Microsoft Access does not support design changes with the version of   Microsoft Sql Server to which your Access project is connected.  See the Microsoft Office Update Web site for the latest information and downloads.  Your design changes will not be saved."*

Again, this is Access 2007 and Sql Server 2005.  My googling efforts - which are coming on a day when I seem to be especially stupid - keep bringing up information regarding this error for Access 2002/2003 trying to connect to Sql Server 2005, which is clearly not my problem.

I'm seeing that one can connect to Sql Server with the normal Access databases (.accdb in 2007 or some such), but I'm seeing mixed information regarding whether I want to do this or not.  And since I can't get a copy of Access 2007, I can't really test this (topic for another time).

Before I do down that road, I'd like to get to the bottom of this one.  Anyone have any suggestions, useful links, or useful knowledge?  Or an older developer who knows the answer that is no longer needed, so I can eat him and absorb his knowledge and powers?

Comment: "so I can eat him and absorb his knowledge and powers" Dude if it worked that way I'd be The Pizza God by now :)

Comment: Or your grand Kegmasterness ;)

Answer (score 2):

The account being used to connect to the DB was only a db_reader.  I changed it to DBO and that fixed the problem - user can now create and save queries, and sleep at night knowing that tomorrow will bring a new day with new querying possibilities.

I'm not super crazy about this though the reporting database has been set up on a separate install/server from impotant App databases.  I'm not worried about the user (or anyone on his group) blowing anything up.  I'd like to understand why this is, and don't (outside of the obvious - reader is read only!  I didn't expect that to extend to work in Access), and will try to do so at a later time.  One of the unfortunate aspects of working at a dev shop focused on internal app development is, "well, it's working, you have other things to see to".

Comment: There are finer grain controls on accounts in MS SQL, that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I can be of help here.

But you can have a view inside Access which connects to SQL database and use that view.
Alternatively, you can go the other way. Have a DB project with SQL Server & create a linked server to MS-Access DB.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try linking to the tables through an ODBC connection?

Answer (score 0):

CodeSlave, I did not.  The attitude from higher up is "it's working, move on".  I'm not sure the boss really wanted to go down that road anyway, but it's a moot point.  I should probably try granting the account dbreader and dbwriter access and see if that accomplishes the same thing, but it being dbo isn't really a huge deal.  Or rather, it's not a big enough deal that The Powers That Be want me to seek an immediate change.

I was going to try linked tables until changing the SQl Server account permissions "fixed the problem" (quotes very deliberate; it feels like one of those solutions you arrive at without a proper understanding of what it worked, which vexes me).